# Use SoundPlayerAction-Resource in EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `SoundPlayerAction` specified as resource like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
<SoundPlayerAction x:Key="ButtonClickSound" Source="/Resources/ButtonClick.wav" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Now I would like to reference this resource inside an `EventTrigger` of a `Style`. What I want to do is something like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
{DynamicResource ButtonClickSound}
</EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this does not work. Is there some way I can reference the resource from within the `EventTrigger`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can do exactly what you want purely in XAML without any code. However, you should be able to play a sound using a `SoundPlayerAction` element in an `EventSetter`... try something more like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseDown">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <SoundPlayerAction Source="/Resources/ButtonClick.wav" />
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You can't use a `Resource` here, but you can data bind to the [`SoundPlayerAction.Source` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.soundplayeraction.source(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseDown">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding SoundSource}" />
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

Then at some later stage:

```
SoundSource = "/Resources/ButtonClick.wav";
```

Comment: this works, but I would like to specify the sound file as a resource, because I will have to change the path to the sound file based on some configuration